# Apply custom sum over numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, math, optimization, vectorization

I would like to do this particular computation: with a square ndarray `A` in 4 dimension of size (N, )*4, I would like to compute the 2 dimension array `B` such that

```
for n in range(N):
    for m in range(N):
        B[n, m] = sum(A[i, j, n-i, m-j] for i in range(n) for j in range(m))
```

Is it possible to vectorize this computation with numpy?

It somehow looks like a kind of convolution, but on one array only

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to visualize the whole array action

```
N=4; A = np.arange(N**4).reshape(N,N,N,N)
```

this tests the same:

```
for n in range(N):
    for m in range(N):
        I = np.arange(n)[:,None]; J = np.arange(m)
        B[n,m] = A[I,J,n-I,m-J].sum()
```

It's harder to "vectorize" the `n,m` since the indexed portion of `A` changes with `n` and `m`.  At the last iteration:

```
In [248]: n,m
Out[248]: (3, 3)

In [249]: A[I,J,n-I,m-J]
Out[249]: 
array([[ 15,  30,  45],
       [ 75,  90, 105],
       [135, 150, 165]])
```

while if either n or m is 0, it's an "empty" array with sum of 0.